# Follow behaviour with transform.LookAt on Unity2d

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

So i've been trying to make an enemy follow my player on Unity2d using `transform.LookAt`.
While it does follow the player, It also rotates the enemy as well in 3D but my sprite is made for 2d so the sprite just vanishes. Any ideas?

```cs
//follows player
transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speedEnemy * Time.deltaTime);

//make enemy look towards player
transform.LookAt(target);
```

Comment: You may want to consult [previous Q&A on this topic](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/139515/39518) too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```html
using UnityEngine;

 public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
 {

 public Transform target;
 public float speed = 3f;

 private void Update()
 {
     if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position) > 1f)
     {
         MoveTowards(target.position);
         RotateTowards(target.position);
     }
 }

 private void MoveTowards(Vector2 target)
 {
     transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);
 }

 private void RotateTowards(Vector2 target)
 {        
     Vector2 direction = (target - (Vector2)transform.position).normalized;
     var angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg; 
     var offset = 90f;
     transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.forward * (angle + offset));
 }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I more or less get the code that you posted after some research except for direction.Normalize(); what does it exactly do? I didn't really get the explanation in the documentation.

Comment: @loverofthefeet It returns just the direction of the vector, rather than the vector multiplied by its length. We don't need length, just direction, so we normalize the vector. Sometimes you get unexpected results when you don't normalize the vector, sometimes you don't. It depends on what's being done.